# How to get next post within query. Please write it in

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to pull in the next post. So if you on blog post page A, pull in B on the bottom, with the image, excerpt, and a link. If you are on B, then pull in page C's post on the bottom. I am showing 1 post. I got it all to show the most recent post, but I need to show the next post instead.

Here is my code.

```
            <?php
            $nextpost = get_next_post();
            $recentid = get_the_ID();
            $the_query = new WP_Query( ['posts_per_page' =>1, 'post__not_in' =>[$recentid] ]);
              ?>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 no-pad-all">
            <div class="featured-post-image">

                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

                ?>

            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                the_post_thumbnail( [300, 300], array( 'class'  => 'recent-post-img' ));
            } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_next_post()` function to grab the following post in the loop.

Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php 
$nextPost = get_next_post();
$nextPostExcerpt = get_the_excerpt($nextPost->ID);
$nextPostThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, 'thumbnail');
if($nextPost): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $nextPost->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo $nextPostThumbnail; ?></a>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $nextPost->ID ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $nextPost->post_title ); ?></a>
    <?php echo $nextPostExcerpt; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```